# upload WCF service to host somee.com?

Tags: wcf, configuration, web-config, hosting, host

Link (http://futuregreatdoctor.somee.com/WcfSvcSiteMCAT/service.svc) it work
. But I upload my service to somee, it doesn't work :( (http://nck.somee.com/Server/Service1.scv)

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://nck.somee.com/Server/"/>
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <services>
      <service name="Server.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Server.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <add name="Service1.svc" verb="Service1" path="Service1.svc" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Help me please!

Comment: It's a typo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196985/232821

Answer (score 1):

http://nck.somee.com/Server/Service1.scv you spelt it wrong. I can see it just fine when I do 
http://nck.somee.com/Server/Service1.svc

Answer (score 0):

I see 404 error when I open http://nck.somee.com/Server/Service1.scv

This most probably means that IIS is not properly configured.

Try to put static file (html or txt) in the folder where your Service1.scv is stored.

Make sure that you can open that static file using URL like http://nck.somee.com/Server/myfile.htm to check that IIS sees your files folder.

Update:

IIS shows path it uses to find service -  d:\DZHosts\LocalUser\Kycomputer555\www.nck.somee.com\Server\Service1.scv

Is it correct path?

Answer (score 0):

Host a WCF service in IIS
If your WCF service has an extension .svc you need to add a Managed handler for that extension in your Web.Config file.

Web.Config Handler configuration examples:

v3

v4

http://somee.com/doka/DoHelpTopics.aspx?docode=false&thnid=113